# Monitoring multiple servers

Tags: linux, debugging, monitoring

I am required to run a couple of batch scripts at frequent intervals on multiple servers. This requires me to log in to each server every time.Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question title says you want to "monitor" the servers, but your description implies you only need to run scripts. Do you actually need to view the outputs or just to run the scripts?

Comment: I need to view the output as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use a screen manager such as `screen` or `tmux` to keep the sessions alive if you need an interactive session to do your monitoring.

If you just need to poll for data, `ssh` allows you to pass a command like this

```
ssh username@hostname 'command'
```

You can stick this into a bash script and use `cron` to run it regularly.

Answer (score 1):

Install a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) at these servers. Then, it depends on the servers and infrastructure how you can access the output, if you need it.